# Upload files for Stripe managed account verification issue

Tags: html, forms, file-upload, stripe-payments

I am trying to upload file (from Chrome browser on Linux machine ) to Stripe's server, the response from Stripe's server is

> com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: File for key file must
>         exist.

The problem comes due to   **C:/fakepath/file-name**  from form submit path
when I hard code its original path while upload, it works!

How I can resolve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message does not come from Stripe's API, but rather from the Java bindings themselves: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/c7d26216b09a5a5b288ef5550c59979209979bc5/src/main/java/com/stripe/net/LiveStripeResponseGetter.java#L529-L530

To reuse the [example](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#create_file_upload) from Stripe's [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api#intro):

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_...";

Map<String, Object> fileUploadParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
fileUploadParams.put("purpose", dispute_evidence);
fileUploadParams.put("file", new File('/path/to/a/file.jpg'));

FileUpload fileUpload = FileUpload.create(fileUploadParams);
```

would cause the exact same error if `/path/to/a/file.jpg` does not exist.

Comment: I have same code as you given, there in no issue if I hard code my path in new File("my-path"), is is due to  C:/fakepath/file-name

Comment: original path is  /home/user/documents/file-name  but it taken from form file   as C:/fakepath/file-name

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This error simply means that the file you passed as the value does not exist (or is not accessible by your web application).

Comment: I read the fake path is generated by  browser itself for security purpose but it should  resolved by web application, if not resolving what I needs to do?

Comment: when I replace that fake path with original path it works fine!